Char variable in C
Im trying to do a Menu with do while loop and call some function. But when i reinput the char variable "pick" it return nothing.
int main() {
    char pick;
    int x;
    int *a;
    do {
        printf("Menu of task\n");
        printf("a.Generate an array:\n");
        printf("b.Sort a given array of names to increasing alphabet\n");
        printf("q.Quit\n");
        scanf("%c", &pick);
        getchar();

        switch (pick) {
            case 'a':
                printf("Input N:\n");
                scanf("%d", &x);
                a = tax(x);
               for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
                    printf("%d ", *(a + i)); 
               printf("\n");

                break;
            case 'b':
                printf("Nah:\n");
                break;
            case 'q':
                printf("Out!");

                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong syntax\n");
                break;


        }
    }
        while (pick != 'q');

}

I don't know if it wrong in the case a code or somewhere because when i delete all the scanf in case a it run normally

Suppose the first iteration of the loop reads 'a' into pick.  Then scanf("%d"... reads the digits that you enter interactively but does not read the \n. On the next iteration, scanf("%c", &pick) reads the \n and then blocks on getchar.  Just stop using scanf.

Or write scanf(" %c", ... (with a space before the %c).  But, really, stop using scanf.

Also, update your program with the tax() function which probably where you go wrong.  Arrays in C start at index 0 so for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++) looks wrong

Note: *(a + i) => a[i]

@Yunnosch No worries, it was not a great answer yet, and whoever downvoted it got one in before I deleted the answer till it is in better shape.


But when i reinput the char variable "pick" it return nothing.
How do you know you input nothing?  Do you check the return value of scanf() and check it?  I don't see it.


Just add a leading space in the scanf() function and your problem will be solved.
scanf(" %c", &pick);

Problem:

When you don't add the leading space, the c-compiler takes the \n (ASCII value 10) as the input.

You can check this by printing the value at the end of switch statement
  printf("The value: %d", pick); // will print 10


When you add the leading space, the compiler skips any whitespace characters (including newline characters).



Maybe point out that it's the \n from scanf("%d", &x); that cause the problem as op uses getchar() to remove the \n from the scanf() call you mention?  Or maybe you assume windows so it's \r\n line terminator?
